# Did Guy Ritchie pay homage to Charlie Chaplin in the first Sherlock Holmes movie?

Tags: sherlock-holmes-2009, modern-times

Upon re-watching Charlie Chaplin's classic film, *Modern Times* (1936), I was struck by the similarities between the conclusions of the shipyard scenes in both Chaplin's film and the first *Sherlock Holmes* movie  - namely a lingering shot of a half-built ship sinking in the river;

[image: *Modern Times*]

[image: *Sherlock Holmes*]

I would like to know if there is any documented evidence of Ritchie paying homage to his fellow British director.

Comment: The scenes are similar enough that it would be extremely remarkable if this were a coincidence. I bet Ritchie knew what he was doing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would actually place my money on Robert Downey Jr. having more to do with it, since he won an Oscar nomination for playing Charlie Chaplin in 1992, and therefore surely has seen *Modern Times* several times.

Comment: I did indeed wonder about this, but I'm not sure even Downey Jr has enough clout to push an expensive shot like this into the film. That said, I can imagine he and Ritchie discussing the idea together. Food for thought!